# Can Java Threads be executed in multiprocessor environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system

I have learnt while studying operating system concepts that there are two types of Threads : Kernel level and User level.

I also learnt that Kernel level threads or processes can be executed in multiprocessor environments too.

I have basic doubt regarding Java threads (being user level threads),
can we use them to execute in multiprocessor environment ?

Comment: Use fork-join framework to handle multiprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

First the answer is yes. You can make use of your multi-core processors' full power by creating multiple threads in java.

According to what I know, jvm employs a mixed thread model including both kernel threads and user threads. It has a strategy to decide when to create which type of threads. I believe that when the system resource is abundant, it will tends to create kernel thread and assign java thread object to run on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are talking about the good old Java 1.1 “green threads”. This was a kludge for operating system’s not having a native thread support, or at least no stable support. This feature does not exist in current JVM implementations any more, at least when talking about the reference implementation from Oracle. Java threads are always kernel threads on these JVMs.

So the answer is, yes, Java threads will benefit from SMP aka Multicore CPUs. It requires the operating system to have a native thread implementation, but without it the entire SMP machine would not make much sense. And the JVM must be able to use it, which is the case in all common systems.

Comment: But multiprocessing depends on kernel, and as operating system concepts says that kernel is unaware of user level threads, so how could it recognizes schedule java threads on multiple processors?

Comment: The are no user level threads. Read my answer again: “Java threads are always kernel threads on these JVMs”.

Comment: May be I am not quickly catching you, but it is known to JVM process that java threads are kernel level threads, but my question is how original operating system kernel know it? Because scheduling decisions are taken by original kernel scheduler only. Isn't it?

Comment: How do you create a kernel thread? I would say, regardless of which operating system, the only way to create them is to call a kernel function (or an operating system’s function which delegates to a kernel function) so obviously the kernel knows when a kernel thread exists. The JVM has to call these function when creating or at least when starting a `Thread`.